# How to write GUI in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface

I would like to try to write a GUI application in Python. I found out that there are a lot of ways to do it (different toolkits). And, in this context, I have several basic (and I think simple) question?

1. Is it, in general, a good idea to write a GUI application in Python?
2. What is the standard (easiest and most stable) way to create a GUI applications in Python?
3. Does anybody can give me a link to a simple Hello World GUI application written in Python?

Comment: Duplicate of all of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+gui.  Specifically this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842075/practical-gui-toolkit

Answer (score 6):

1. Depends on what application you are writing. I would use Python for a simple GUI, yes.
2. Use a proper toolkit (such as [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) - Python bindings for the popular Qt)
3. Sure

Hello world in PyQt:

```
import qt,sys

a = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = qt.QPushButton("Hello World",None)

a.setMainWidget(w)
w.show()
a.exec_loop()
```

Comment: i think u can speedy develop by use qtdesigner and pyuic to get a looking good ui in python , :)

Answer (score 4):

I am really fond of pygtk and glade. Pygtk is a python binding for gtk, the gui toolkit used in gnome. Glade is a user interface designer which stores a gui as xml, which can be loaded in pygtk.

- http://www.gtk.org/
- http://www.pygtk.org/
- http://glade.gnome.org/

If you want to see some example code, you can take a look at my project https://launchpad.net/pumped. Just download the source.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to make a fairly simple GUI, then PyGTK is extremely easy to use:

http://www.pygtk.org/

A tutorial (with downloadable sample code) can be found [here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html), and another one on the [Wiki](http://live.gnome.org/PyGTK/QuickStart).

Answer (score 2):

As an answer for #1: Yes.  It is quite good for this; scripting languages with GUI toolkits are often a good way to put a GUI on an application.  They can also be used to wrap applications written in low level languages such as C or C++.  Python offers good integration to quite a few toolkits.  The posting linked above gives a pretty good cross section of the options with code samples.

For #2: TkInter comes with the standard distribution.  It is easy to use but not as sophisticated as (say) QT or WxWidgets.

Comment: I tried the Tkinter and my program writes "ImportError: No module named _tkinter, pleas install the python-tk package".

Comment: @Roman: we need to know which platform you are using. Presumably you are either using Windows and didn't include Tk when installing Python, or you are using Unix/Linux and you need to install a seperate package.

Answer (score 1):

python is ok for gui better than perl and ruby heres some tk

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
ttk.Button(root, text="Hello World").grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn some GUI programming in Python using Tkinter, you can see a step-by-step process of building a simple MineSweep clone in twelve progressions here: [MineSweep for Python 3.x](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577365-minesweep/)